# how to save data received form postman OneToMany and ManyToOne using lombok in Sprngboot jpa

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I want to save data to database by taking data from postman. i dont know how to save this and how to map this.
Entities

```
@NoArgsConstructor @AllArgsConstructor@ Data
@Entity
public class user{  
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    private String name;
    private String mobileno;
    private String role;
   @OneToMany(mappedBy = "bill", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<Bill> bill;
}
```

```
@NoArgsConstructor @AllArgsConstructor@ Data
@Entity
public class Bill{  
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    private String billno;
    private Integer amount;
    private Integer qtyinbill;
   @ManyToOne
    private User user;
}
```

repo

```
public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User, Long> {
    
}
```

data fro postman

```
{
"name":'"jack", "mobile":"1234567890", "role":"ROLE_ADMIN",
"bills":[{"billno":'"st1001", "amount":10000, "qtyinbill":4},{"billno":'"st1002", "amount":4000, "qtyinbill":7}]}
```

Controller

```
@PostMapping("/bill")
    public String saveBill(@RequestBody User user) {
// how t0 save to database
}
```

Comment: Start learning here: https://spring.io/projects/spring-data

Comment: can you write the code to save it.